# Dynamic method dispatch/Run-time polymorphism

Tags: java

How and when exactly the objects are created at run time? Where is the dynamic binding taking place? Can you give real time example for this?
I know it binds method call to method implementation at run time based on object type! Practically want to see how it happens?
Answer with the picture would be great!!

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This Example will help you to understand the dynamic binding.

```
class Parent{
    int value = 10;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    int value =20;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
public class RunTimePolymorphism {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setValue(100);
        System.out.println(child.getValue());

        Child child1 = new Child();
        System.out.println(child1.getValue());

        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.setValue(200);
        System.out.println(parent.getValue());

        Parent parent1 = new Child();
        System.out.println(parent1.getValue());


    }
}
```

Hope So, it will help you to understand Runtime Polymorphism.